# Bluemix. App doesn't start when service "Monitoring and analytics-op" is bound

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, analytics, monitoring

We have an app "SDK for Node.js" with a node/express api. We can push, restart, etc. and everything works fine.

But if we bind the service "Monitoring and analytics-op" the app never starts.

The log shows this node error:

```
ERR /home/vcap/app/node_modules/knj-plugin/lib/deep-dive/method-probe.js:197
ERR at Object.exports.attach (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/knj-plugin/lib/deep-dive/probes.js:9:12)
ERR at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vcap/app/common/utils/index.js:6:14)
ERR at Module.newFunc (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/knj-plugin/lib/aspect.js:47:19)
ERR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
ERR at Array.forEach (native)
ERR if(Object.keys(target.prototype).length==0 && Object.keys(target).length == 0){
ERR at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/knj-plugin/lib/plugin.js:36:23
ERR at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
ERR at /home/vcap/app/node_modules/knj-plugin/lib/deep-dive/probes.js:10:24
ERR at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
ERR ^
ERR at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
ERR at Object.exports.attach (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/knj-plugin/lib/deep-dive/method-probe.js:197:13)
ERR npm ERR! Linux 3.19.0-33-generic
ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
ERR npm ERR! node v6.3.1
ERR npm ERR! npm v3.10.3
```

Comment: It seems a defect in method-probe, but to be sure and precisely locate the problem. Could you please help provide:

    which Node.js version are you using (if you set the "engines" in package.json)

    diagnostics or free plan are you using? (if you are using diagnostics plan, please switch to free plan before this issue is fixed, that will provide less information in your performance dashboard, but at least it will make sure your application runs well)

    If it is possible I wish I can have your sample application, it will help us fix your problem quickly.(yuecchen@cn.ibm.com)

Comment: Please try with the latest Bluemix environment, we fixed the defect that cause the error log you posted in latest buildpack.

Answer (score 0):

You could be running into an issue where you need to allocate more memory.  The M&A service can require up to 110 MB of space on your application environment to store your app's log data. You should ensure that you have at least 110 MBs  of space in your application environment.

Note: If you're using the M&A free plan, you must ensure that the Memory Quota for the app is **at least** 512 MBs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems at though this is a problem with BlueMix's module - there is [at least one other reported defect](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/254748/monitoring-and-analytics-service-breaking-nodejs-e.html) in method-probe per the IBM Developer Forum. This error is with method-probe attaching into your code and failing.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me, updating npm to 3.10...

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/answers/309483/view.html